# CodeIgniter: Can't load database from within a model

Tags: database, codeigniter, model

I've written a new model for my CodeIgniter framework.
I'm trying to load the database from within the constructor function, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Severity: Notice
Message:  Undefined property: userdb::$load
Filename: models/userdb.php
Line Number: 7

Fatal error:  Call to a member function database() on a non-object in 
/var/www/abc/system/application/models/userdb.php on line 7
```

Here is my model:

```
<?php

class userdb extends Model {

    function __construct() {

        $this->load->database();

    }
?>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're forgetting to call the parent constructor first. Something like:

```
<?php

class userdb extends Model {

function __construct() {

    parent::Model();

    $this->load->database();

}
?>
```

Comment: Call to undefined method CI_Model::Model() in application/models/Xyz_manager.php on line abc

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it would cause a problem or not, but Model names are supposed to have the first letter capitalized. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html Jens is also correct that you need to call the parent constructor as well.

Comment: That was my first thought as well - CodeIgniter naming conventions require capitalized class names. I was going to write that until I noticed the missing constructor call ;)

Comment: `parent::Model();` did the trick. As for the Uppercase letter in the class/model name, I really hate it but I changed it to avoid possible errors. Thank you for your help.

Comment: How is this the best answer when it didn't even specified the correct answer? Jens below answered correctly.