# Codeigniter Call to a member function database() on a non-object in

Tags: database, codeigniter, autoload

Yes yes yes, I already searched over whole internet about this problem. Some results found, even from Stackoverflow. But most of them say "You should autoload database", or "parent::__construct();" like codes. I tried mostly all of them. Still no result. Its just killing me.

I have table named "we". I just need read data from it.

**Model:** application/models/we_model.php

```
 class We_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_all_we() {

        $query = $this->db->get('we');
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

**Controller:** applicatoin/controllers/home.php

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('we_model');
    }

    public function index() {

        $data['we_lists'] = $this->we_model->get_all_we();
        $this->load->view('home_template_view', $data);
    }
}
```

**Autoload:** application/config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'form_validation');
```

**Screenshot:**
[image: Error screenshot]

I'm using Codeigniter 2.1.3, Wampserver 2.2e, PhpStorm 5.0.4 and following [this](http://www.w3programmers.com/introduction-to-codeigniter-basic-with-crud/) tutorial.

**Update:**
I read [this forum](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/218108/#1006613). He said after he switched his editor from Eclipse to Dreamweaver, code worked. So I changed my IDE, from PHPStorm into Sublime text 2. Code works now. Can you explain?

Comment: Perhaps the same issue as this question?[1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686814/codeigniter-cant-load-database-from-within-a-model

Comment: I'm already looking into it. I added parent::Model(); but still same.

Comment: I changed my editor. I used Sublime Text 2. Now it works. What's happening!??!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't autoloading the database library (and honestly you really should be) change this line:

```
$this->load->database();
```

to

```
$this->load->library('database');
```

Comment: Call to a member function library() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\shohtg\application\models\we_model.php on line 8

Comment: oh... okay if it can't even load a library there is something screwed up with your CI base install. There is no way that should be throwing any sort of error.

Comment: fml. Can you review it by teamviewer or some remote control soft?

Comment: Try adding: $autoload['libraries'] = array('database'); to autoload.php in the config folder. Remove the line from the constructor in your we_model entirely. I'm just leaving the office and don't have any remote software installed anyway sorry

Comment: But I already have code in autoload.php :( `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'form_validation');`

Comment: Then remove that line entirely from the model, it isn't needed. Not sure if that is throwing the error but it certainly isn't helping, nor necessary. Autoloading the database library will connect to the db without you having to explicitly state it. for that matter remove the constructor function, it's extending CI controller so it's already using it's constructor.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to call `$this->load->database();` in your model

just use this in autoload.php:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

Comment: I put this line because code didn't worked. Now its already removed. And If you read my Update, code working now. But I don't know why worked, I just changed IDE and started from scratch. Every single line is same as old.