# CodeIgniter CLI returns blank when utilizing a model. How to run cron securely?

Tags: codeigniter, command-line, cron

I am trying to run a cron from the command line utilizing CodeIgniter.

Initially it was returning a blank but utilizing the Codeigniter forum I found there was a bug in version 2.1.3 which required a line edit in Input.php

That was fixed. Still it wasn't working, it was just loading my homepage.

More searching led me to change my uri_protocol to AUTO in my config, and finally the CLI was working with the example outlined on the CI website.

However when I have utilized a model in the cron controller, once again the CLI returns blank *bangs head*

The controller

```
<?php

class Cron extends CI_Controller
{
   public function admin_update()
   {

      $this->load->model('admin_model');
      $this->admin_model->admin_cron(); 
   }
}
```

The model function

```
function admin_cron()
{
   $this->load->database();
   echo "two";
}
```

It seems to be the $this->load->database() line that is breaking it.. as in if i remove this it outputs 'two'..

Does anyone have any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you had an error log, have you tried loading library in another way?
From codeIgniter user_guide, to call a library you woul do:
$this->load->library('database');

Comment: Im not loading a library.. it is a model..

Comment: I am sorry. What is this line for: $this->load->database();
Is database a model or a library?
As far as I can see the model is the $this->load->model('admin_model');
so, what exactly is the line load->database(), is database another model?

Comment: No.. thats just how you load a database in CodeIgniter...

Comment: Does this help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686814/codeigniter-cant-load-database-from-within-a-model

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing any input for $this->load->database();

Instead it should be something like this

```
var $DB; //global variable
$this->DB = $this->load->database('database1',TRUE);
```

use $this->DB for running the db operations now like,

```
$this->DB->query($query);
```

Put these config enteries in the config/database.php

```
$db['database1']['hostname'] = 'serverIP';
$db['database1']['username'] = 'username';
$db['database1']['password'] = 'pwrd';
$db['database1']['database'] = 'DB name';
$db['database1']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['database1']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['database1']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['database1']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['database1']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['database1']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['database1']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['database1']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['database1']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['database1']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['database1']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

PS: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html#conn

above link is on how to connect to a database